# Command to determine which characters occur in file

Tags: linux, file, character

I'm looking for a Linux/UNIX command that will determine the distinct characters in a file. Character counts would be nice, but not essential. For example, if I run the command on a file containing this data...

```
This is
my data
file.
```

...it would give me this as output...

```
T h i s m y d a t f l e .
```

...or even better, this.

```
T:1 h:1 i:3 s:2 m:1 y:1 d:1 a:2 t:1 f:1 l:1 e:1 .:1
```

In the output, the order of the characters doesn't matter, nor does it matter whether they are separated by spaces, tabs, lines, etc.

Comment: Care to explain why you don't think this belongs here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print unique characters:

```
$ grep -o . file | sort -u | tr -d '\n'
 .Tadefhilmsty
```

To count the number of occurrences of each character:

```
$ grep -o . file | sort | uniq -c
      2
      1 .
      1 T
      2 a
      1 d
      1 e
      1 f
      1 h
      3 i
      1 l
      1 m
      2 s
      1 t
      1 y
```

I'll leave the formatting to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any unix command that will do it, but it's possible to get what you want with a small python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections, sys
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for line in sys.stdin:
    for c in line:
        d[c] += 1
print dict(d)
```

will give the result

```
{'a': 2, ' ': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 3, 'h': 1, '\n': 2, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, '.': 1, 's': 2, 'T': 1, 'y': 1, 't': 1}
```

Comment: +1 This is quicker than the accepted solution, which makes a big difference for large files.